# Computing injective resolution of some constant sheaves

Tags: homological-algebra, sheaf-theory

I follow the notations on "Sheaves on manifolds" written by Kashiwara-Schapira. Let $\mathbb{K}$ be a ground field and $X$ be a smooth manifold. Let $D(X)$ be the derived category of sheaves of $\mathbb{K}$-vector spaces. In this category, I want to compute an injective (or flabby) resolution of a constant sheaf $\mathbb{K}_U$ (resp. $\mathbb{K}_Z$) where $U$(resp. $Z$) is an open (resp. closed) subset of $X$ to compute the image of the constant sheaf via the right derived functor of global sections $R\Gamma(X;\mathbb{K}_U)$ (resp. $R\Gamma(X;\mathbb{K}_Z)$).